# magento 2 checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout

I face an issue on checkout age regarding the auto-update date when we enter the city and zip code on the checkout page. I want to remove auto-updating when we enter the city it should only update when I enter a zip code.

Answer (score 1):

Make this fields blank
[image]

**Hope it works!!**

Comment: Its already blank but when on checkout page when i enter city in city field it update data and loading start for few seconds i don't want this ,it should only happens on zip code field not on city. how can i do that?